# GeoServer cascading WMTS: Error rendering coverage on the fast path / Base URL cannot be null

Tags: geoserver, wmts

GeoServer 2.15.2 on Ubuntu 18.04

Although there are similar questions here and elsewhere, I couldn't find anything that would help me, unfortunately.

Apart from my own data sources, I am cascading WMS through my GeoServer; a governmental background map, e.g., is running fine. Yet I cannot get our aerial images (store = WMTS) to display in the layer preview (or through QGIS), the message being "Error rendering coverage on the fast path. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Base URL cannot be null" (see log below).

```
2020-07-08 16:09:35,315 INFO [geoserver.wms] - 
Request: getMap
    Angle = 0.0
    BaseUrl = https://wald.expert:443/geoserver/
    Bbox = SRSEnvelope[387985.38246145623 : 612566.3045180056, 5264331.035645437 : 5516503.024465457]
    BgColor = java.awt.Color[r=255,g=255,b=255]
    Buffer = 0
    CQLFilter = null
    Crs = PROJCS["ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N", 
  GEOGCS["ETRS89", 
    DATUM["European Terrestrial Reference System 1989", 
      SPHEROID["GRS 1980", 6378137.0, 298.257222101, AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]], 
      TOWGS84[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
      AUTHORITY["EPSG","6258"]], 
    PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0, AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]], 
    UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295], 
    AXIS["Geodetic longitude", EAST], 
    AXIS["Geodetic latitude", NORTH], 
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4258"]], 
  PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator", AUTHORITY["EPSG","9807"]], 
  PARAMETER["central_meridian", 9.0], 
  PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin", 0.0], 
  PARAMETER["scale_factor", 0.9996], 
  PARAMETER["false_easting", 500000.0], 
  PARAMETER["false_northing", 0.0], 
  UNIT["m", 1.0], 
  AXIS["Easting", EAST], 
  AXIS["Northing", NORTH], 
  AUTHORITY["EPSG","25832"]]
    Elevation = []
    Env = {}
    Exceptions = SE_XML
    FeatureId = null
    FeatureVersion = null
    Filter = null
    Filters = null
    Format = application/openlayers
    FormatOptions = {}
    Get = true
    Height = 768
    Interpolations = []
    Layers = [org.geoserver.wms.MapLayerInfo@ecc1465c]
    MaxFeatures = null
    Palette = null
    RawKvp = {REQUEST=GetMap, SRS=EPSG:25832, FORMAT=application/openlayers, BBOX=387985.38246145623,5264331.035645437,612566.3045180056,5516503.024465457, VERSION=1.1.0, SERVICE=WMS, WIDTH=683, HEIGHT=768, LAYERS=waldexpert:DOP_20_C}
    RemoteOwsType = null
    RemoteOwsURL = null
    Request = GetMap
    RequestCharset = UTF-8
    ScaleMethod = null
    Sld = null
    SldBody = null
    SldVersion = null
    SortBy = null
    SortByArrays = null
    SRS = EPSG:25832
    StartIndex = null
    StyleBody = null
    StyleFormat = sld
    Styles = [StyleImpl[ name=generic]]
    StyleUrl = null
    StyleVersion = null
    Tiled = false
    TilesOrigin = null
    Time = []
    Transparent = false
    ValidateSchema = false
    Version = 1.1.0
    ViewParams = null
    Width = 683
2020-07-08 16:09:35,742 INFO [geoserver.wms] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
2020-07-08 16:09:35,743 ERROR [geoserver.ows] - 
org.geoserver.platform.ServiceException: Error rendering coverage on the fast path
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.produceMap(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:355)
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.produceMap(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:269)
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.produceMap(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:132)
    at org.geoserver.wms.GetMap.executeInternal(GetMap.java:707)
    at org.geoserver.wms.GetMap.run(GetMap.java:287)
    at org.geoserver.wms.GetMap.run(GetMap.java:110)
    at org.geoserver.wms.DefaultWebMapService.getMap(DefaultWebMapService.java:251)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor425.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.geoserver.kml.WebMapServiceKmlInterceptor.invoke(WebMapServiceKmlInterceptor.java:38)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CacheSeedingWebMapService.invoke(CacheSeedingWebMapService.java:55)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CacheSeedingWebMapService.invoke(CacheSeedingWebMapService.java:31)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CachingWebMapService.invoke(CachingWebMapService.java:72)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CachingWebMapService.invoke(CachingWebMapService.java:52)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.geoserver.ows.util.RequestObjectLogger.invoke(RequestObjectLogger.java:50)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy49.getMap(Unknown Source)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor387.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.execute(Dispatcher.java:877)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:264)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:998)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:890)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:875)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:26)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:69)
    at org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:66)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:41)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:37)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:51)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:52)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:142)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:42)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:46)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:42)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:607)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http2.StreamProcessor.service(StreamProcessor.java:355)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.http2.StreamProcessor.process(StreamProcessor.java:72)
    at org.apache.coyote.http2.StreamRunnable.run(StreamRunnable.java:35)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.geoserver.platform.ServiceException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Base URL cannot be null
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.directRasterRender(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:1222)
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.produceMap(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:353)
    ... 123 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Base URL cannot be null
    at org.geotools.tile.TileService.setBaseURL(TileService.java:78)
    at org.geotools.tile.TileService.<init>(TileService.java:73)
    at org.geotools.ows.wmts.client.WMTSTileService.<init>(WMTSTileService.java:106)
    at org.geotools.ows.wmts.request.AbstractGetTileRequest.getTiles(AbstractGetTileRequest.java:235)
    at org.geotools.ows.wmts.WebMapTileServer.issueRequest(WebMapTileServer.java:148)
    at org.geotools.ows.wmts.map.WMTSCoverageReader.getMap(WMTSCoverageReader.java:285)
    at org.geotools.ows.wmts.map.WMTSCoverageReader.read(WMTSCoverageReader.java:262)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.gridcoverage2d.GridCoverageReaderHelper.readSingleCoverage(GridCoverageReaderHelper.java:638)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.gridcoverage2d.GridCoverageReaderHelper.readCoverage(GridCoverageReaderHelper.java:214)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.gridcoverage2d.GridCoverageRenderer.renderImage(GridCoverageRenderer.java:866)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.gridcoverage2d.GridCoverageRenderer.renderImage(GridCoverageRenderer.java:829)
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.directRasterRender(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:1058)
    ... 124 more
```

The URL is https://owsproxy.lgl-bw.de/owsproxy/ows/WMTS_LGL-BW_ATKIS_DOP_20_C?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMTS

The GeoTools dev log points (below, I hope that's the relevant part) to a mismatch between the tile matrices and my grid set? I need to define my tile matrix set as it is in the WMTS, right?

```
2020-07-13 17:03:37,526 DEBUG [org.geotools.ows.wmts.request] - getTiles: layer:WMTS LGL-BW ATKIS DOP 20 cm Bodenauflösung
2020-07-13 17:03:37,526 DEBUG [org.geotools.ows.wmts.request] - getTiles:  layer:WMTS LGL-BW ATKIS DOP 20 cm Bodenauflösung w:683 x h:768
2020-07-13 17:03:37,526 DEBUG [org.geotools.ows.wmts.request] - request CRS EPSG:ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N
2020-07-13 17:03:37,527 INFO [org.geotools.ows.wmts.request] - Failed to match the requested CRS (EPSG:ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N) with any of the tile matrices!
2020-07-13 17:03:37,527 DEBUG [org.geotools.ows.wmts.request] - defaulting matrix set:ADV_31467_Quad
2020-07-13 17:03:37,527 DEBUG [org.geotools.ows.wmts.request] - Format not set, trying with image/png
2020-07-13 17:03:37,527 INFO [org.geotools.ows.wmts.request] - Template URL not available for format  image/png
2020-07-13 17:03:37,527 DEBUG [org.geotools.ows.wmts.request] - Available formats: [image/jpeg, image/png] -- Selecting image/jpeg
```

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: can you tell us some more about the WMTS layer you are loading and how you set it up

Comment: Thank you, Ian. The end of my original message got removed. My questions is: how can I resolve these error messages while trying to cascade a WMTS through my Geoserver?
The WMTS layer contains orthophotos and is published by our regional government, accessible with user name and password. I am adding this external service to my stores as described in the docs (https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/cascaded/wmts.html). I can add my layer, using tile caching and the default style (raster) and enable it; but the preview and access from qgis fails with that error message.

Comment: Is there anything else I can provide? Please let me know if is this questions is unanswerable as it is posed or otherwise insufficient? Thanks!

Comment: can you tell us some more about the WMTS layer you are loading and how you set it up

Comment: I am not sure how to explain more about the layer and my setup apart from what I wrote above. Anything specific you are missing? In the meantime I was setting up the same orthophoto layer as a WMS (both WMS and WMTS are offered by the agency, under different addresses) abd that is working as expected. Does that help to localise the error with WMTS?

Comment: what URL are you cascading, how did you set up the cascade layer - the error says you have not set up the base url correctly, turn logging up to GeoTools dev and try again

Comment: edited the question above observing your suggestions